# The signature file 'AsyncSocket' does not have a corresponding implementation file

Tags: f#, .net-4.5

I'm just getting started off with F#, so there could be something very simple that I'm missing, but I'm getting a compiler error that no one seems to have run into:

> The signature file 'AsyncSocket' does not have a corresponding
>   implementation file. If an implementation file exists then check the
>   'module' and 'namespace' declarations in the signature and
>   implementation files match.

I thought it could be something wrong with my code, so I copied the [example from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233196.aspx) and I'm getting the exact same thing.  Any idea what's happening?

Signature:

```
namespace Library1
  module Module1 = 
    val function1 : int -> int
    type Type1 =
        new : unit -> Type1
        member method1 : unit -> unit
        member method2 : unit -> unit

    [<Sealed>]
    type Type2 = 
        new : unit -> Type2
        member method1 : unit -> unit
        member method2 : unit -> unit

    [<Interface>]
    type InterfaceType1 =  
        abstract member method1 : int -> int
        abstract member method2 : string -> unit
```

Implementation:

```
namespace Library1
module Module1 =

    let function1 x = x + 1

    type Type1() =
        member type1.method1() =
            printfn "test1.method1" 
        member type1.method2() =
            printfn "test1.method2"


    [<Sealed>]
    type Type2() =
        member type2.method1() =
            printfn "test1.method1" 
        member type1.method2() =
            printfn "test1.method2"

    [<Interface>]
    type InterfaceType1 =
        abstract member method1 : int -> int
        abstract member method2 : string -> unit
```

Comment: You should make sure that the signature file comes before the implementation file in file ordering. Think of a signature file as a contract that the implementation should fulfill.

Comment: @pad: In VS 2012 that gives a different error: _An implementation of file or module 'File1' has already been given. Compilation order is significant in F# because of type inference. You may need to adjust the order of your files to place the signature file before the implementation. In Visual Studio files are type-checked in the order they appear in the project file, which can be edited manually or adjusted using the solution explorer._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs if the signature and implementation files have different names (sans extensions). The signatures and implementations should be in separate files named `<same-name>.fsi` and `<same-name>.fs`, respectively. As pad commented, the signature file should immediately precede the implementation file in the build order (or Solution Explorer treeview).

Comment: Quite right, my implementation file had an 's' on the end of it!